# How to find the filenames changed between to linux directories as per contents of the file using md5sum followed by diff command

Tags: bash

I have two linux directories dir1 and dir2 with some files in both. Now i want list of filenames with files added and files deleted in dir2 as compared to dir1. The files should be compared as per the data or contents in the file. I am new to the linux bash scripting. Please help me.

Currently i am doing this like below :

```
find dir1 -iname *.c -o -iname *.h -o -iname *.prm | xargs -n1 md5sum > dir1.fingerprint.md5sum
find dir2 -iname *.c -o -iname *.h -o -iname *.prm | xargs -n1 md5sum > dir2.fingerprint.md5sum
cat dir1.fingerprint.md5sum | cut -d" " -f1 | sort -u > dir1.fingerprint
cat dir2.fingerprint.md5sum | cut -d" " -f1 | sort -u > dir2.fingerprint
diff -NrU 2 dir1.fingerprint dir2.fingerprint
```

I am getting the result as some change id's as shown below :

```
--- dir1.fingerprint    2013-03-08 11:57:24.421311354 +0530
+++ dir2.fingerprint    2013-03-08 11:57:34.901311856 +0530
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-43551a78e0f5b0be4aec23fdab881e65
-4639647e4f86eb84987cd01df8245d14
4c9cc7c6332b4105197576f66d1efee7
+9f944e70cb20b275b2e9b4f0ee26141a
+d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

I want the result as the filenames for files modified or added newly to dir2. How to get this. Please help me.

Comment: Does it work with the added lines?

Comment: made some changes. working now. test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script with the arguments dir2 and dir1

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "x$1" == "x" ]
then
exit 0
fi
if [ "x$2" == "x" ]
then
exit 0
fi
#echo "DIFF $1 $2"
if [ -f $1 ]
then
        if [ -e $2 ]
        then
                diff $1 $2 >/dev/null
                if [ "$?" != "0" ]
                then
                        echo "DIFFERENT $1"
                fi
        fi
        exit 0
fi
if [ "x`ls $1`" != "x" ]
then
        for f in `ls $1`
        do
                $0 $1/$f $2/$f
        done
fi
exit 0
```

EDIT:

```
if [ "x`ls $1`" != "x" ]
then
        for f in `ls $1`
        do
           if [ -f $1/$f ]
           then
              for g in `ls $2`
              do
                  if [ -f $2/$g ]
                  then
                      diff $1/$f $2/$g >/dev/null
                      if [ "$?" == "0" ]
                      then
                          echo "SAME CONTENT $1/$f $2/$g"
                      fi
                  fi
              done
           fi
        done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks uba for the reply. But diff command won't compare the difrectory files as per contents of the file. right?? I want that also to taken care of. Also i am getting few errors while running the above script. I am running the script as :                              stack.sh dir1 dir2                  and i am getting the errors : [: 5: xdir1: unexpected operator
[: 9: xdir2: unexpected operator
[: 5: xdir1/file1.c: unexpected operator
[: 9: xdir2/file1.c: unexpected operator
dir1/file1.c NEWLY ADDED
[: 5: xdir1/file1.h: unexpected operator
[: 9: xdir2/file1.h: unexpected operator

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with the way i am doing it. I am getting the results just not getting the filenames. Instead i am getting file IDs.

Comment: The problem is that the `sh` shell does not seem to support the square bracket conditionals. `bash` supports them. So in the script, the first line `#!/bin/sh` should be replaced with the path for `bash` which would probably be `#!/bin/bash`. If there is still some problem, add the output that you are getting so that I can figure out the problem. On my system, it works fine.

Comment: This working for the modified files. But for the file in dir1 which is renamed in dir2 it should show as renamed. How to do this.

Comment: Nope.. that would get pretty complicated.. Involving comparison of each file with each other one, I think.. Will think about it and get back.. I hope half the issue is solved at least(modified files with same name)?

Comment: any ohter way to get the complete solution. ??

Comment: I have added some lines to the solution. Add them to the script and see if it works. Add the lines before `exit 0;`

Comment: exactly before which exit 0 i should add the above lines. i added before the last exit 0 but still it is showing the file as newly added.

Comment: Does it not give a "SAME CONTENT" output?

Comment: it is showing the "SAME CONTENT" as output, but the before that it also shows that the file is newly added, because it first enters into the else block of the first if. How to avoid this

Comment: delete the two lines `else
                echo "$1 NEWLY ADDED"` corrected it now..